# What does this syntax mean in fortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am working on a project and as I have not coded with Fortran before, I am struggling a lot. My professor gave me a code file which I need to fix but I don't understand the syntax.

So, in the file he has

```
         g = some formula,
     1        some formula
     2        * some formula
     3        / some formula.
```

What does 1, 2, 3, * and / do?

I asked my Professor, and he said that this is Fortran 77 code and 1, 2, 3 are used as indexing in column 6 and the g is in column 7 as that's how the Fortran code is written. But I was very confused why Fortran 77 only accepts code after column 7?

Thank you for all the replies.

Comment: Could you give more context? Like, a bigger piece of code or a program unit. Also, do you know if it is fixed format or free format?

Comment: It's probably fixed format Fortran (note the spelling, lower-case) , but until you show us the exact code we can't be sure

Comment: The numbers look like line numbers, that a "goto" might refer to

Comment: It would be useful to know what position on the line those numbers appear.  Fixed-form Fortran has rules which mean, among other matters, that a `1` in column 1 of a line means something different in column 6, and different again in later columns.  Unfortunately SO code formatting doesn't respect the fixed-format.

Comment: As @HighPerformanceMark already mentioned the formatting (especially for Fortran) is important. Looks like there a 4 spaces "eaten" by SO. Megha edit the question so it is clear what the spacing is (maybe use triple backquotes to start and end the code section) also, give as stated before, some more context.

Comment: Hi, all I know is that this is a fortran 77 code and uses the formatting for f77.

Answer (score 10):

What you are most likely looking at is ***Fixed source-form statement continuation***  which is part of the *Fixed source form*.

Fixed-form formatting is an old way of formatting code which still stems from the old [punched-cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card).  Lines could only be 72 characters long, but sometimes you needed more. Hence, the statement-continuation character:

> Except within commentary, character position `6` is used to indicate continuation. If character position `6` contains a blank or zero, the line is the initial line of a new statement, which begins in character position `7`. If character position `6` contains any character other than blank or zero, character positions `7–72` of the line constitute a continuation of the preceding non-comment line.
>
> **<sub>source: [Fortran 2018 Standard, Section 6.3.3.3](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf)</sub>**

Which character is used as statement-continuation marker, is up to the programmer and his style. Often you see a <ampersand>-character (`&`), or <dollar>-character (`$`) or the <asterisk>-character (`*`) like so:

```
c23456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
      g = something long
     &    + something_longer
     &    + something_even_longer
```

However, in the really old days, people often numbered their lines.

```
c23456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
     0g = something long
     1    + something_longer
     2    + something_even_longer
```

and because space was limited, they removed all spaces, which sometimes becomes very confusing when you have numbers in your line:

```
c23456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
     0g=1.2345+
     10.35697-
     22.5789
```

This does not add 10.35697 and subtract 22.5789, but adds 0.35697 and subtracts 2.5789

The usage of numbers as statement continuation markers is again inherited from the punched-cards. A single punched-card represented a single Fortran statement. And on the card, the row and column numbers were printed (Thanks to [High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744634/what-does-this-syntax-mean-in-fortran/59750212?noredirect=1#comment105647123_59750212) for this information)

[image]

---

**Note:** the asterisk and slash in the OP are nothing more than the normal multiplication and division.

Comment: *in the really old days* the numbers were printed at the top of the punch card !

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for this information. I did not know this at all. I've added this a bit into the answer.